# How to get bytes from Groovy Markupbuilder

Tags: groovy, inputstream

I need to create a new ByteArrayInputStream from a groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder object. I need to pass the bytes to the inputstream constructor, but I have no idea how to access them. JDom does this like this:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = builder.build(someInputstream);
...
XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
someInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputter.outputString(doc).getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

But I can't find a way to do something similar using MarkupBuilder

Answer (score 3):

You can do this sort of thing:

```
InputStream ins = new StringWriter().with { sw ->
    new MarkupBuilder( sw ).build {
        node {
            woo( 'yay' )
        }
    }
    new ByteArrayInputStream( sw.toString().getBytes( 'UTF-8' ) )
}
```

Comment: how should we add xml declaration <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>